Is De Polignac's conjecture equivalent with the the statement that for any positive even $n$, there are infinitely prime pairs with difference $n$?
Suppose $n$ is a positive even integer. I wonder if the following two statements are equivalent:
(1) There are infinitely many pairs of consecutive primes with difference $n$.
(2) There are infinitely many pairs of primes with difference $n$.
It's trivial to see that (1) implies (2). The converse is trivial for $n = 2$, and also the case $n = 4$ is easy to prove (I used that one of $p$, $p+2$ and $p+4$ is divisible by 3, so if $p \geq 5$ and $p$ and $p+4$ are both prime, there are no primes between them). I'm stuck for $n \geq $6 however. Does anyone know a result regarding this question? Many thanks!

I don't see any way of ruling out the case $n = 6$.  AFAIK it is quite conceivable that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+6$ is prime, but in all but finitely many of these cases $p+2$ or $p+4$ is also prime. Of course this would contradict other conjectures, but those are only conjectures.

It is strongly conjectured that every even prime gap occurs infinite many often although the case is even open for not necessarily consecutive primes. The best unconditionally proven result is that infinite many prime gaps exist not exceeding $246$.
